# how to pass model from view to controller at jqgrid grid load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am very beginner in asp.net mvc.I have the model defined for the view which has all data required to process at ApplicationService whenever there is an update action.

How to pass that model to controller from view. For example, when i edit a row and to save that row into database, i need few details to manipulate the row before saving that data to database.
All required data i have in the model to perform manipulation in that row.

```
@model mymodel.MyViewModel
.
.
.

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: 'mycontroller/updatemethod',
        datatype: "json",
        postData : //i dont know how to pass model to controller here
        colNames: ['Id','First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 
                'Age', 'Salary',  "Address",'Marital Status'],
        colModel: [
        { name: '_id', index: '_id', width: 20, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150 },
           { name: 'LastSSN', index: 'LastSSN', width: 100 },
        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Age', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 80, align: "right" },
        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 150, sortable: false },
        { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false }
      ],
        rowNum: 10,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "List Employee Details"
    });
</script> 


[ActionVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
Public ActionResult updatemethod(MyViewModel mymodel)
{
// From viewmodel, I have necessary data to validate before calling database update
}
```

Comment: did you tried using saverow method

Comment: i am not sure how to pass parameter during saverow method. In the controller i am getting the row Model without me passing anything. but now sure how to pass model also to that controller method

Comment: please add your model and controller in your question